# Could i use @Parameters from TestNG to read from a user defined xml and not from testng.xml

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have lot of test data that will be used in various @Test methods. I am planning to use @Parameters to pass my test data for each @Test method(Usually 1-2 parameters per test). But various references suggest that @Parameters reads property defined in testng.xml. I do not want to define all the property names in a single testng XML file and instead want to have separate XMLs so that i can organize my test data too. 
So is it possible to do so? Any other alternative to manage test data?
P.S: Excel is not an option

Comment: You can use the BeforeMethod and pass the Object[] to it. Testng will inject it with the parameters that where going to be passed to the test. You can have your logic in this and override the data in the Object[]. You can define the value of the parameters in testng xml with the name of the xml to look for value, so the logic becomes reusable.

Comment: @Grasshopper, that's a good approach. Thanks! Could you elaborate on how to read the parameter values with the name of the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you :- Have you tried this approach?

You can use data provider also for getting the test data as below :-

```
public class DataProviderTest {

private static WebDriver driver;

@DataProvider(name = "Authentication")

 public static Object[][] credentials() {

    return new Object[][] { { "a", "a" }, { "b", 
"b" }};

 }

 // Here we are calling the Data Provider object with its Name

 @Test(dataProvider = "Authentication")

 public void test(String sUsername, String sPassword) {

  driver = new FirefoxDriver();

  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  driver.get("http://yoursite.com");

  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account']/a")).click();

  driver.findElement(By.id("log")).sendKeys(sUsername);

  driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys(sPassword);

  driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();

  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account_logout']/a")).click();

  driver.quit();

  }

}
```

[You can write logic for reading xml file and can pass that data to dataprovider and use same dataprovider in every test.]

Please let me know whether this helped you. So that I can suggest you other solutions.

Comment: i did consider using dataProvider, but each of my test will be needing a different parameter. Using dataProvider, will run each of my Test multiple times with all the elements in Object[][]. My requirement is that - I want to pass argument say, 'abc' to Test1 'efg' to Test2 and so on. Each test will have unique data being passed and is run only once.

Answer (score 0):

In the testng.xml you will need to add the parameters and in the value you can use a concatenation of the name of the relevant xml file and the name to look for in the xml.

In the BeforeMethod you will get this in the Object[] and then you can create your own logic to split the value. Then parse the XML file and retrieve the actual data. The parsing logic will depend on the structure of your xml, anyways pretty easy with all Java-XML parsers available.

```
    <parameter name="first" value="dataone-first"></parameter>
    <parameter name="second" value="dataone-second"></parameter
```

---

```
    @Test
    @Parameters({"first","second"})
    public void testMeth(int a, int b){

    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void befMeth(Object[] params) {

        for(int j=0;j<params.length;j++){
            String xmlData = params[j].toString();
            String actualValue = logicToParseXMLAndGetValue(xmlData)
            params[j] = actualValue;
        }
    }
```